# React Native iOS image with hyperlink

Tags: ios, image, hyperlink, react-native

I have hyperlinks working ok with `<Text>` but have been unable to get them working with images. I've tried this code:

```
    <Image onPress={() =>
         LinkingIOS.openURL('https://website.com')}
      source={require('./images/picture.png')}>
    </Image>
```

Can't to be honest think of any other way it would be done. It doesn't throw up any error but clicking it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap it in a clickable element, like a TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight, or TouchableWithoutFeedback:

```
<TouchableHighlight 
  onPress={() => LinkingIOS.openURL('https://website.com')}>
  <Image 
    source={{uri: 'http://cf.ltkcdn.net/socialnetworking/images/std/168796-281x281-girl-swear-icon.png'}} 
    style={{height:50, width:50}} />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

I've set up a working example [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/JTSSWQ). Full code is also below.

https://rnplay.org/apps/JTSSWQ

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Image,
  LinkingIOS
} = React;

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() =>
             LinkingIOS.openURL('https://website.com')}>
            <Image 
          source={{uri: 'http://cf.ltkcdn.net/socialnetworking/images/std/168796-281x281-girl-swear-icon.png'}} style={{height:50, width:50}} />
         </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 28,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    fontSize: 19,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: Ok that's great. I'm wondering why a <Text> attribute is a clickable link even without Touchablehighlight though? Anyhow, it works, thanks very much.